# Removing axes in beeswarm plot

Tags: r, scatter-plot, beeswarm

I have a following "beeswarm" (a single-dimensional scatterplot)

```
library(beeswarm)
data(breast)
beeswarm(breast$time_survival,horizontal=TRUE)
```

Here is the resulting plot:

[image]

How can I get rid of the axes and the box around the plot, so that I can reintroduce only the X axis and nothing else around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an empty plot first

```
plot(rnorm(10), type="n", axes=FALSE, xlim=c(0, 200), ylim=c(0.4, 1.6), 
     xlab="", ylab="")
```

Then you can use the `add` argument to get what you want

```
beeswarm(breast$time_survival,horizontal=TRUE, add=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "axes" argument (described in `?plot.default`).

```
beeswarm(breast$time_survival, horizontal=TRUE, axes = FALSE)
```